# Can I use a Custom Field as the Featured Image URL?

Tags: custom-field, post-thumbnails

Each post of my blog has a Custom Field which is the URL of a photo on Flickr. How can I use it as the Featured Image?

Please note I'm asking this question because I'm migrating to a theme that makes use of the Featured Image to display thumbnails on the blog’s home page, but I would avoid enter them all by hand for all the 300+ old posts.

**EDIT:**

- I'd prefer to avoid to change the theme's code, to avoid complications during future updates. But I can use child themes.
- The theme I'm using uses the `get_post_thumbnail_id()` function to obtain the featured image attached to the post:

  ```
  <?php if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) :
  $full_image_url = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID), 'full' );
  ?>
  <div class="post-thumbnail-wrapper">
      <a class="swipebox" href="<?php echo $full_image_url[0]; ?>" title="<?php printf( esc_attr__('Permalink to image of %s', 'envirra'), the_title_attribute('echo=0') ); ?>" rel="bookmark">
          <?php the_post_thumbnail( 'vw_large' ); ?>
      </a>
  </div>
  ```

Comment: Please post the *actual code* from your Theme, that is used to generate the image. Otherwise, there's no way to provide a specific answer. `get_post_thumbnail_id()` merely returns a Post ID for an attachment post-type.

Comment: Based on the posted code, you're going to have to edit your template to accomplish what you're after.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Editing the Template

The easiest solution would be to use a conditional to display the featured image:

`if has custom field use it, else use Featured Image`

You can get the custom field using [`get_post_meta()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post_meta), which will return an empty string if the specified key isn't set:

```
$custom_url = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'old_featured_image_custom_field', true );
```

You can get the Featured Image using [`the_post_thumbnail()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_post_thumbnail), or check for its existence via [`has_post_thumbnail()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/has_post_thumbnail).

Using these, you can set up a conditional output, e.g. like so:

```
<?php
$custom_url = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'old_featured_image_custom_field', true );

if ( '' != $custom_url ) {
    ?>
    <img src="<?php echo $custom_url; ?>" />
    <?php
} else if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) {
    the_post_thumbnail();
}
```

### Using a Filter

If you can't or don't want to edit the template, you're in luck: `the_post_thumbnail()` calls [`get_the_post_thumbnail()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_post_thumbnail), which includes a filter, [`post_thumbnail_html`](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.8/src/wp-includes/post-thumbnail-template.php#L141):

```
return apply_filters( 'post_thumbnail_html', $html, $post_id, $post_thumbnail_id, $size, $attr );
```

So, just write a filter callback using the same method:

```
function wpse129849_filter_the_post_thumbnail( $html, $post_id ) {
    // Try to find custom field value
    $custom_url = get_post_meta( $post_id, 'old_featured_image_custom_field', true );
    // If it has a value, return it
    if ( '' != $custom_url ) {
        return '<img src="' . $custom_url . '" />';
    } 
    // otherwise, just return the original post thumbnail html
    else {
        return $html;
    }
}
add_filter( 'post_thumbnail_html', 'wpse129849_filter_the_post_thumbnail', 10, 2 );
```

Comment: It's a nice idea, but it would require a change to the theme's code. I'd prefer to avoid doing so, to avoid complications during future updates...

Comment: Please see updated answer. You can use a filter as well.

Comment: Thanks! But from what I see my theme uses the `get_post_thumbnail_id()`, not the `get_the_post_thumbnail()`. Any suggestions?

Comment: Before I edit my answer again, please **edit your question** to include all relevant information, including all relevant code in context, your no-template-editing limitation, and anything else that might restrict solutions.